# Extracting the last name from a mixed formatted name column in R

Tags: r, string

I need to separate the last names from a mixed format of names. Here is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 name = c("Jack Smith", "May, Flora", "Jackson","Baker, Gavin","Walls")) 

> df
  id         name
1  1   Jack Smith
2  2   May, Flora
3  3      Jackson
4  4 Baker, Gavin
5  5        Walls
```

I need to extract only the last names. for the first row the last name is `Smith`. For the second row, the last name is `May`, for the third row the last name is `Jackson`. How can I create the last name column as below?

```
 > df
      id         name last_name
    1  1   Jack Smith  Smith
    2  2   May, Flora  May
    3  3      Jackson  Jackson
    4  4 Baker, Gavin  Baker
    5  5        Walls  Walls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that the last name is the first word when a comma is present and that the person only has one last name and it appears last, then do:

```
library(stringr)
df$last = ifelse(str_detect(df$name, ','), 
                 str_replace(df$name, ',.*',''), 
                 str_extract(df$name, '\\S*$'))
```

and you will get:

```
id         name    last
1  1   Jack Smith   Smith
2  2   May, Flora     May
3  3      Jackson Jackson
4  4 Baker, Gavin   Baker
5  5        Walls   Walls
```

When there is a comma, replace from the comma onwards with an empty string. If there is no comma, then grab the last word as the last name.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a combination of regexes.
The first removes whatever is right of a comma.
The second removes whatever Alphabetical characters are before an space followed by a capital letter.

```
library(dplyr)
 
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
           name = c("Jack Smith", "May, Flora", "Jackson","Baker, Gavin","Walls")) |> 
    mutate(last_name = gsub(pattern = "[,].*$",  replacement = "", x = name) |> 
                       gsub(pattern = "^[A-z]+ (?=[A-Z])", replacement = "", x = _ , perl = TRUE))

  id         name last_name
1  1   Jack Smith     Smith
2  2   May, Flora       May
3  3      Jackson   Jackson
4  4 Baker, Gavin     Baker
5  5        Walls     Walls
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution that makes some general assumptions - your real data is probably messier than your sample data, though:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  name = c("Jack Smith", "May, Flora", "Jackson", "Baker, Gavin", "Walls")
)

reformat_name <- function(name) {
  split_name <- stringr::str_split(name, ", ") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    rev() %>%
    paste(collapse = " ")
  
  return(split_name)
  
}

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(stringr::str_detect(name, ", "), reformat_name(name), name),
         last_name = ifelse(stringr::str_detect(name, " "), trimws(stringr::str_extract(name, "\\s[^ ]+$")), name))
         
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id name        last_name
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    
#> 1     1 Jack Smith  Smith    
#> 2     2 Flora May   May      
#> 3     3 Jackson     Jackson  
#> 4     4 Gavin Baker Baker    
#> 5     5 Walls       Walls
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R way:

```r
df$last_name <- mapply(\(n, comma) 'if'(comma, n[1], tail(n, 1)),
                       strsplit(df$name, ',? '),
                       grepl(',', df$name))
df
#   id         name last_name
# 1  1   Jack Smith     Smith
# 2  2   May, Flora       May
# 3  3      Jackson   Jackson
# 4  4 Baker, Gavin     Baker
# 5  5        Walls     Walls
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stringr::str_extract` with `if_else`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
    mutate(last_name = if_else(str_detect(name, ","),
                               str_extract_all(name, "^[A-Za-z]+"),
                               str_extract_all(name, "[A-Za-z]+$")))

  id         name last_name
1  1   Jack Smith     Smith
2  2   May, Flora       May
3  3      Jackson   Jackson
4  4 Baker, Gavin     Baker
5  5        Walls     Walls
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `gsub` to produce a uniform format of names

```
> transform(df,last_name = gsub("\\w+\\s", "", gsub("(\\w+), (\\w+)", "\\2 \\1", name)))
  id         name last_name
1  1   Jack Smith     Smith
2  2   May, Flora       May
3  3      Jackson   Jackson
4  4 Baker, Gavin     Baker
5  5        Walls     Walls
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(last = str_extract(name, "(\\w+)(?=,|$)"))
```

-output

```
 id         name    last
1  1   Jack Smith   Smith
2  2   May, Flora     May
3  3      Jackson Jackson
4  4 Baker, Gavin   Baker
5  5        Walls   Walls
```